# Calculating monthly return from a dataframe that has cumulative return down the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe. How do I create a new column that has the monthly return?

Exhibit A:

| Scenario | TimeStep | CumReturn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1.05 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.07 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1.04 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.02 |

Exhibit B:

| Scenario | TimeStep | CumReturn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | .05 |
| 1 | 1 | .019 |
| 1 | 2 | na |
| 2 | 0 | .04 |
| 2 | 1 | -.019 |
| 2 | 2 | na |

Where row n is (n-1 / n)-1 for each change in time, stopping at the end of each scenario.

The end goal is to do this iteratively for cumulative indeces, then create a linearly combination from the individual returns, then RE roll to a new cumulative number.

I am doing this in pandas.

So far I have this code:

```
  for idx,wght, i in zip( indeces,fundweights , range(len(indeces)-1)):
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(filepath + file_names[idx],header=None)
        df_temp = df_temp.stack()
        df_temp.index.names=['Scen','TIME']
        df_temp= df_temp.to_frame(name='CumGrowth_idx')
        df_temp.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df_temp['Scen'] = df_temp['Scen'] + 1 
        df_temp[idx] = idx
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'TIME':'Month'})
        df_temp["Monthly_Return"]=
```

I want to create the monthly return dataframe, then append these all to a dataframe, take a linear combination. Can anyone offer some input?

Thanks

Comment: Please update your input samples to be properly formatted.  See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1):

While there is probably a much more elegant way to accomplish this with some of Pandas' merge and group methods, here is a method that will work.

First of all define a function to split the dataframe by Scenario Indexs, then update the cumReturn column using the shift function, finally concat the separate frames back into 1 frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def computeDifference(df: pd.DataFrame)-> pd.DataFrame:
    scnslist = df['Scenario'].unique()
    rslt = df[df['Scenario'] == scnslist[0]].copy()
    rslt['CumReturn'] = (rslt['CumReturn'].shift(-1)/rslt['CumReturn'])-1
    for i in range(1, len(scnslist)):
        dx = df[df['Scenario'] == scnslist[i]].copy()
        dx['CumReturn'] = (dx['CumReturn'].shift(-1)/dx['CumReturn'])-1
        rslt = pd.concat([rslt, dx], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return rslt
```

When given the dataframe in Exhibit 1, defined as df
you can execute `computeDifference(df)` which yields:

```
    Scenario    TimeStep    CumReturn
0   1   0   0.050000
1   1   1   0.019048
2   1   2   NaN
3   2   0   0.040000
4   2   1   -0.019231
5   2   2   NaN
```

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by using shift however I did not need to loop.. as I used group by for the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df_temp = pd.read_csv(filepath + file_names_equity[idx],header=None)
        df_temp = df_temp.stack()
        df_temp.index.names=['Scen','TIME']
        df_temp= df_temp.to_frame(name='CumGrowth_idx')
        df_temp.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df_temp['Scen'] = df_temp['Scen'] + 1 
        df_temp[idx] = idx
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'TIME':'Month'})
        
        df_temp["Monthly_Return"]= (df_temp["CumGrowth_idx"].div(df_temp["CumGrowth_idx"].shift(1)) - 1).shift(-1)
        df_temp["Monthly_Return"] = np.where(df_temp['Month'] == 600,0, df_temp['Monthly_Return'] )
```